# Find equation of a parabola given slope of tangent line at two x values and a point on the curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

I'm stuck on this Calculus problem about finding a parabola with the equation

$y=ax^2+bx+c$

I know the slope of $3$ at x=1 and slope of $-13$ at $x=-1$,  and know that the parabola passes through the point $(1,1).$

Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: You should be able to make a system of equations.  You know that f'(1)=3 and f'(-1)=-13 and that f(1)=1.  That's a system of three variable with three equations that you can solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c$. We know the following:

\begin{cases}
f'(1)=2a+b=3\\
f'(-1)=-2a+b=-13\\
f(1)=a+b+c=1
\end{cases}

This system has solution $a=4, b=-5$ and $c=2$. So the parabola you are looking for has equation $$y=4x^{2}-5x+2.$$